# Run celery periodic task for 1 hour, it it takes more then 1 hour, expire that task?

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I have a periodic task for data purging which run once a day.

I want that task to run only for 1 hour. If the duration of processing that task is more than 1 hour, then expire that task. It will run again the next day for 1 hour.

I would like to do this is because if the traffic is high then that particular cerely task keeps on running for 10-15 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up the task time limits as per [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#time-limits)

If you are going to set it on particular task you can use 
[`task_time_limit`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-soft-time-limit) or [`task_soft_time_limit`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-soft-time-limit) depending on your usage characteristics

Answer (score 9):

I've found that the most reliable way to do this is first to set global limits in `settings.py`, where the value is an `int` in seconds:

```
 CELERY_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 3540
 CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 3600
```

Then, you can catch the soft time limit exception and clean up your task before the hard limit hits:

```
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

@shared_task
def mytask():
    try:
        return do_work()
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        cleanup_in_a_hurry()
```

See the [celery settings docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-time-limit) for more details.

You then override `soft_time_limit` and `time_limit` when you define individual tasks, for example:

```
@shared_task(soft_time_limit=60, time_limit=70)
def mytask()
    ...
```

There are some more details in the [task docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.time_limit).